# i need to copy bitmap image file in c language using a buffer

Tags: c

i have to copy a bitmap image file using a buffer. 
here is an example of what i need to do.
i have to read different parts of a bitmap into the buffer first at once and then write it to the target file.
when i read different parts into the buffer , the previous string gets overwritten and the last string that is read is only written. i dont want to use read and write function for every part that has to be written.
please help me with the code.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void fskip(FILE *fp, int num_bytes) {
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_bytes; i++)
    fgetc(fp);
}

int main() {
  FILE *fp, *fp1;

  fp = fopen("c:\\users\\tapan\\desktop\\splash.bmp", "rb");
  fp1 = fopen("c:\\users\\tapan\\desktop\\splash2.bmp", "wb");

  int *j;
  j = (int *)malloc(3000);

  int k = 223121;
  int *i = &k;

  fread(j, 2, 1, fp);

  fread(j, 10, 1, fp);
  fwrite(j, 12, 1, fp1);

  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp);

  getch();
}
```

Comment: Out of all the issues with this code, the one pertinent to your question is because the first `fread` writes to your buffer, but then the second `fread` also writes to that buffer, overwriting the original `fread` contents.

Comment: but how do i move the pointer in buffer so that it doesn't get overwritten?

Comment: You will need to use pointer arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I will try to address your specific question and avoid any comments about other things in the code.

It looks like the `fread()` and `fwrite()` statements are not correct.  The following code might be more exact.

```
   int main() {
     FILE *fp, *fp1;

     fp = fopen("c:\\users\\tapan\\desktop\\splash.bmp", "rb");
     fp1 = fopen("c:\\users\\tapan\\desktop\\splash2.bmp", "wb");

     int *j;
     j = (int *) malloc(3000);

     int k = 223121;
     int *i = &k;

     // read 2 items of sizeof(int) into j from fp
     fread(j, sizeof(int), 2, fp);

     // read 10 items of sizeof(int) into j + 2 from fp
     fread(j+2, sizeof(int), 10, fp);

     // write 12 items of sizeof(int) from j to fp1
     fwrite(j, sizeof(int), 12, fp1);

     fclose(fp1);
     fclose(fp);

     getch();
   }
   // Note. The above code has NOT been tested, it is thrown-up here for discussion.
```

Format of `fread()` and `fwrite()` is per K&R, second edition, page 247.